# Foreign networks doesn't works reliable on Macbook

Tags: macos, wireless-networking, wifi-configuration

Every time I connect to a foreign network (secure or open), it only works sometimes. For example. I'm in London at the moment. Here I have to connect to a WPA-secured network. Sometimes my laptop can connect to the network, but it has no internet-connection.

[image]

If i than run the tool that should check the network, sometimes it asks for the password. I write it in but osx says, it isn't correct. But it is, because I sometimes can connect with this. And it is 100% correct. Really strange.

Sometimes I can't connect to the network at all, because of timeout.

At home I can connect immediately without changing anything or putting in a static IP.

I was able to connect to this network, when I did put in the IP-address, the Gateway and the subnetmask by myself.

But after some time, the network-connection crashes and I have to change something to connect again. But I can't reproduce, what the crash causes, or why sometimes it works. Right when I'm typing this, the connection crashed again. But there is no error-message. Only there is no connection anymore. If I now connect to the network there is always the "no-internet"-symbol. And sometimes the MacBook doesn't even found the network anymore.

My current IP-configuration is/was:

> 192.168.1.113
>   255.255.255.0
>   192.168.1.254

I'm using a MacBook Pro with the following configuration:

> 15", Early 2011
>   OSX 10.8.4
>   2.2 Ghz Intel Core i7
>   8GB 1333Mhz DDR3 RAM 
>   AMD Radeon HD 6750M
>   Bootcamp installed

What could cause this problem. I've also Bootcamp installed, and also on Windows there are the same problems. But I can connect to this network with my smartphone without any problems. (with static ip)
Some days it works the whole day without any problems. But there has to be a problem with my laptop, because the WLAN always works with my smartphones.

Comment: How many devices are on the network? It could be the DHCP-addresses are all in use. When you put in a static one it can work for a moment until the other device wakes up. Does your phone get a dynamic ip (if you disable the static one on the phone)?

Comment: No they aren't because there are over 100 adresses open.

Comment: Then the only thing I can think of is poor connection. It could be only effecting your Macbook if your phone has a stronger antenna. Either way, assigning a static ip only masks the problem because if your computer can't reach the DHCP-server it's already a sign of an underlying problem. Try diagnosing it like Spiff said.

Answer (score 0):

Mac OS X has a hidden Wi-Fi Diagnostics feature. Hold down the <kbd>option</kbd> key while clicking on the Wi-Fi Menu Extra, then select "Wi-Fi Diagnostics…" from the bottom of the menu.

Comment: I will give it a try when I'm at home